# How to create an SSH tunnel and access remote service from behind firewall with HTTP proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I want to access a remote service running on a vps on `<remote>:8888` but our campus network blocks all ports except for `80`,`443`,`8080`. And using a web proxy `172.16.0.2:8080`, but each time my connection is refused, by the web proxy/firewall I presume.

I can SSH into into the remote server after I have bound `sshd` to port `8080`; i.e. `<remote>:8080`.

How can I access my service running on `8888` on the server? I can’t bind the service to `80` as that is used for Apache.

I am using [MobaXterm](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mobaxterm&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) but I can also use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).